# Pass query result in SQL Server function

Tags: sql-server, slack-api, slack

I am working on Slack integration with SQL Server. I have the following function to send data to slack.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SlackChatPostMessage(
    @Token      nvarchar(max),
    @Channel        nvarchar(max),
    @Text       nvarchar(max),
    @UserName   nvarchar(max),
    @IconUrl        nvarchar(max)
) 
RETURNS TABLE(
    Ok          bit,
    Channel     nvarchar(max),
    TimeStamp   nvarchar(max),
    Error       nvarchar(max)
) AS EXTERNAL NAME      SqlServerSlackAPI.UserDefinedFunctions.SlackChatPostMessage;
GO
```

**My objective** is to send the result of a query to slack. I am successful in sending a simple text to slack using @Text variable in the function. However, I am unable to **implement** how I can pass a query result instead of simple text.

Hope the question is clear.

**SOLUTION**: 
Easiest way is to create a static cursor and use a loop to pass every row into this function.

Answer (score 1):

Function SlackChatPostMessage does not take any table variable input, if your query returns a table, you cant pass that table value, if it is a single value output from your query use this before you send it to the function

```
convert(nvarchar,(yourquery))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One way which I got is by using Cursors. Is that correct?

Comment: you mean sending the data one by one using cursor?

Comment: Yes. I did it. Thanks alot! :)